# How to get extra column from stored prcedure when i call in ef core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeManagers]
@ID INT  
AS  
Begin
SET FMTONLY OFF;
WITH   subordinate AS (  

    SELECT  Id,  
            Name,  
            Surname,
            BirthDate,
            PositionId,
            ManagerId,
            CreatedDate,
            DeletedDate,
            IsDeleted,
            ModifiedDate,
            1 AS [Managing Level]  
    FROM Employees  
    WHERE Id = @ID  
   
    UNION ALL  
   
    SELECT  e.Id,  
            e.Name,  
            e.Surname,
            e.BirthDate,
            e.PositionId,
            e.ManagerId,
            e.CreatedDate,
            e.DeletedDate,
            e.IsDeleted,
            e.ModifiedDate,
           [Managing Level] + 1
    FROM Employees e  
JOIN subordinate s  
ON e.Id=s.ManagerId
)  
   
  
SELECT    
    m.Id ,  
    m.Name,  
    m.Surname,
    m.BirthDate,
    m.PositionId,
    m.ManagerId,
    m.CreatedDate,
    m.DeletedDate,
    m.IsDeleted,
    m.ModifiedDate,
    s.[Managing Level]  
FROM Employees m

JOIN subordinate s 
ON s.ManagerId = m.Id

ORDER BY [Managing Level];
end
```

This is my stored procedure which get Employee Managers. Which get All employee managers and give them managing level

```
        public string Name { get; set; }
      
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public int? PositionId { get; set; }
        public Position Position { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeDepartments> EmployeeDepartments { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
        public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Employee Entity

When I call stored procedure it return only Employee Entity fields but I also want get Managing Level

```
        public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeeManagers(int employeeId)
        {
        
            var parameter = new SqlParameter("@ID", employeeId);
            var managers = _context.Employees.FromSqlRaw("spManagersTable @ID", parameter);
            return managers;
        }
```

I can't get Managing Level it is work but i also want to get Managin Level.
I need get also managin Level in my Employee entity

Comment: In your with clause, you unioned one filtered row with the ID value of the Employees table with the rest of the "Employees" table, which I'm sure the filtered row with ID would repeat since you unioned them. The only difference would be the unioned record would have [Managing Level] + 1. You also joined the subordinate table in your with a clause that you didn't reference. Then you joined the "subordinate" with clause result with the "Employees" table again. I'm not sure what you are trying to retrieve from the database. Would you elaborate more?

Comment: I try to get All Mangers of the Entered Employee

Answer (score 0):

First scenario, WITH clause return IDs for the Manager with the Id of `@ID` and employees with the MangerId of `@ID`. Then, it selects the Employees only matching those IDs with all the columns you may need to retrieve.

```
WITH subordinate AS (  
    SELECT  Id,  
            1 AS [Managing Level]
    FROM Employees  
    WHERE Id = @ID
   
    UNION ALL  
   
    SELECT  Id,  
            2 AS [Managing Level] 
    FROM Employees
    WHERE ManagerId = @ID AND Id != @ID
    ORDER BY [Managing Level] ASC;
)   
  
SELECT 
    e.Name,  
    e.Surname,
    e.BirthDate,
    e.PositionId,
    e.ManagerId,
    e.CreatedDate,
    e.DeletedDate,
    e.IsDeleted,
    e.ModifiedDate,
    e.[any other column 1],
    e.[any other column 2],
    e....
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN subordinate s ON e.Id = s.Id
ORDER BY s.[Managing Level] ASC
```

Or you can simply use OR operation which returns the manager as well as the employees with the manager id of `@ID`:

```
SELECT 
    Name,  
    Surname,
    BirthDate,
    PositionId,
    ManagerId,
    CreatedDate,
    DeletedDate,
    IsDeleted,
    ModifiedDate,
    [any other column 1],
    [any other column 2],
    ..
FROM Employees
WHERE (ManagerId = @ID or Id = @ID)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ManagerId = @ID THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
```

Comment: This is not excatly what i want my stored procedure work when i call this procedure in entity framework sp return Employee entitites but I want to it retun only the columns which I write in sp but i found solutin I use Sqlreader and read return data to dto thanks for your answer